# How do I replace a value in a list with the average of its adjacent values?

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I need to clear up missing data which are denoted by -99. If my function detects a missing data, it has to replace the missing data with the average of the values adjacent to it. However, if an average cannot be calculated because of consecutive missing data, then the missing data would have to be replaced by the immediate adjacent values. I tried to write a code for the replacement but it doesn't seem to be working. Did i do something wrong at the 'if' part? I can't use `pandas` or `numpy` so only the basic python functions are allowed.

```
def cleanup(data):
    missing_value = -99
    for num in range(len(data)):
        if num == missing_value:
            data[num] = (data[num-1] + data[num+1])/2
    return data 

data = [[1, 2, -99, 4, 5], [1, 2, -99, -99, 5],[1, 2, 3, -99, -99]]
cleanup(data)
```

expected output

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: Why does your expected output only have two sublists but your data has three?

Comment: yes i just realised and have edited it!

Comment: Would it be possible to have 3 missing values in a row ?  what should you do if that happens ?

Comment: @AlainT. yes if its [1, 2, -99, -99, -99] then it should return [1, 2, 2, 2, 2]

Comment: The example [1, 2, -99, -99, -99] is an edge case. What about [1, 2, -99, -99, -99, 5]? How the middle -99 should be filled?

Comment: @tchar the problem given to me only has 2 consecutive -99 so it should be able to return the adjacent values!

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` parameter is a list of lists so you will need to use a nested loop to process each sub-list independently.

For each of the sub-lists, you can use `zip` to obtain the previous, current and next values in one expression.  applying `enumerate` on that will also give you the indexes.

Given that you will potentially need to propagate values over more than one position, using a `propValue` variable to track the propagation value will make it easier to manage.  You can initialize that with the first non-missing value in the sub-list.

With the previous (P), current (V) and next (N) values, it is then only a matter of checking the condition for replacement of the missing value at the current index (i).  You also need to update the propagation value as you encounter non-missing values in the sub-list.

```
def cleanup(values,missing=-99):
    for values in data:                  # loop through list of lists
        propValue = next(v for v in values if v is not missing) # 1st non-missing
        for i,(P,V,N) in enumerate(zip([missing]+values,values,values[1:]+[missing])):
            if V is not missing: propValue = V         # skip non-missing values            
            elif N is missing:   values[i] = propValue # propagate forward
            elif P is missing:   values[i] = N         # propagate backward
            else: values[i] = (P+N)//2       # use average when both present
```

Output:

```
data = [[1, 2, -99, 4, 5], [1, 2, -99, -99, 5], [1, 2, 3, -99, -99],
        [1, -99, -99, -99, 5], [-99, -99, 3, 4, 5] ]
cleanup(data)
print(data)                                 

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 2, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
 [1, 1, 1, 5, 5], [3, 3, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote your function to deal with a list of integers, but then you gave it a list of lists.  Look at the loop structure:

```
for num in range(len(data)):
    if num == missing_value:
```

`num` is an integer subscript; in this case it iterates over the values 0, 1, 2.
This will *never* be equal to -99.

You have to change this to work with the lists within the input argument, and then to run through the values in each list:

```
for sub_list in data:
    for idx in rang(sub_list):
        if sub_list[idx] == missing_value:
```

Can you take it from there?

Please note that you should *now* learn basic debugging.  If nothing else, learn to place strategic `print` commands to show the values you're using.  Had you done this with your posted program, you would have seen the values you were comparing.

Comment: I wanted to run cleanup(data) on one list first to see if it works before applying it to the list of list. so can i check if this that i added is correct? data[num] = (data[num-1] + data[num+1])/2

Comment: Yes, you can check: fix your loop to use that form of reference, run the code, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I think Alain's answer is probably the one you want, but I'll also list the version I put together which differs slightly in the following ways:

1. It handles ranges of missing values > 2 differently, whereas the previous answer propagates the value forward, this one averages the middle value, so that the average of all the values is unaffected.
2. This one doesn't modify the input, your original returned a modified input so the two answers here have gone in the different directions one not bothering to return the value you already have, and this one returnig you a new list of lists.
3. The average is floored division in the other answer whereas this one returns the mean, so if your expected result for the first missing item is 3 then you probabaly do want to use // instead of the / oepration here.
4. Alain's answer is also a lot pretty than mine! This one is a lot more primitive, but perhaps it is still interesting as an alternative approach.

- 

```
def cleanup_series(data,missing=-99):
    c = []
    p = next(v for v in data if v != missing)
    if len(data):
        st = -1
        for n in range(len(data)):
            if data[n] == missing:
                if st == -1:
                    st = n
                nd = n
            else:
                if st > -1:
                    r = (1+nd-st)//2
                    c.extend([p]*r)
                    if (nd-st)%2==0:
                        c.append((p+data[n])/2);
                    c.extend([data[n]]*r)
                    st = -1
                c.append(data[n])
                p = data[n]
                n += 1

        if st > -1:
            c.extend([p]*(1+nd-st))

    return c

def cleanup(data):
    return list(map(cleanup_series, data))

data = [[1, 2, -99, 4, 5], [1, 2, -99, -99, 5],[1, 2, 3, -99, -99],[1, 2, -99, -99, -99, 4, 5],[-99,-99,2]]
print(data)
print(cleanup(data))
```